# How to send message to microsoft teams using python script?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I want to send message to Microsoft teams channel. I have a VM and i want to run python script inside VM and want to use rest API to send message to microsoft teams channel.

1. I tried with generating access_token using client_credentials flow , but it throws following error
   {'error': {'code': 'Unauthorized', 'message': 'Message POST is allowed in application-only context only for import purposes. Refer to https://docs.microsoft.com/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/import-messages/import-external-messages-to-teams for more details.', 'innerError': {'date': '2023-02-06T15:26:59', 'request-id': 'ec5838d3-8d3c-4b59-b177-b261a934901f', 'client-request-id': 'ec5838d3-8d3c-4b59-b177-b261a934901f'}}}
2. I tried with generating access_token using code authorization flow , but in this flow, we need to generate code in the browser , which is not automated way
3. I tried with generating access_token using password flow, it throw following error
   {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'.\r\nTrace ID: 6ace8bef-c2f5-43c4-a9a5-16955e5c7b01\r\nCorrelation ID: a6e6dc2b-1257-4aed-9579-f447e064cabd\r\nTimestamp: 2023-02-06 15:41:38Z","error_codes":[50076],"timestamp":"2023-02-06 15:41:38Z","trace_id":"6ace8bef-c2f5-43c4-a9a5-16955e5c7b01","correlation_id":"a6e6dc2b-1257-4aed-9579-f447e064cabd","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=50076","suberror":"basic_action"}